# Broadcastreceiver declared in manifest gets no output to Log.d

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have declared MyBroadcastReceiver on the manifest. My class is extending BroadcastReceiver. When I try to get a reaction from it neither System.out.println prints something nor Log.d - the only way to get info from the system is via Toast. 
Is is possible to get it to work or this is just the way it is.

API min and max = 16.
I am using an Android-version (as opposed to Google)
I am using an emulator Android API 16.

Comment: you need to post some code for us to look at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `android:debuggable="true"` in the `<application>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Also make sure your ADT plugin is 100% up-to-date, because I'm pretty sure that you don't have to do this anymore in order to get logs to display in the logcat. Also, don't forget to remove this tag in the future if you ever publish it to Google Play.

Comment: It works! I get a warning in the xml that I should not do like that, however now I can both see Log.d and System.out.println. Thanks!